# Combine two columns of a dataframe and then compare

Tags: python, r, dataframe, bioinformatics, string-comparison

I have a dataframe of 3 columns and 859 rows. The dataframe is like

df1:

```
MacroNode                                     Prefix                               Suffix
AAACCGCCAATATCTCGACGAGAAAAGCGAC      GCCAACTGGATAACCACGCCCTG                GCCAACTGGATAACCACGCCC
ATTTCTGCGAGGTGCAGGGCAATTACATCAT       TAGGCCTT                               AAAACCCTTGGAA
```

These are basically the node and prefix and suffix edges of a graph:

```
macronode + suffix = prefix of next macronode + that next macronode
```

I have to see what is the maximum stretch i can achieve by the rows present in this data frame. Thus I think first I have to combine the rows and then compare. But I am not able to understand how to do this. Any ideas are welcome.

**Expected Outcome**

I am giving a short dataframe here

Toy df:

```
MacroNode        Prefix          Suffix
 GC                T               A
 CA                G               C
 AC                C               T
 CT                A               A
```

As you can see here if you take the macronode's characters with the suffix character of the first row (GC + A) it is equal to the next row's prefix character + that next row's macronode's characters (G + CA).

But in my dataframe there is no guarantee that the rows are contiguous like in the toy example here I mentioned.

Then the output shall look like
The maximum continuous path is :
TGCAGCACCACTACTA which is 16 characters.

First few rows of the original dataframe:

```
    MacroNode                         Prefix                               
 1. AAACCGCCAATATCTCGACGAGAAAAGCGAC   GCCAACTGGATAACCACGCCCTGAGACTCAAGGGCGT
 2. AAACTTCTGCCGGAATATAAAGCCGCGCCGG   AGCAAAGCGCGCCACTTCACCCTGAGCTT
 3. AAAGCATTGTGGCCGGAACCGATGACGCGCC   CGGCGTCCCCTGGATGATGGCTTT
 4. AACACCACGCTGGAGATGGTTGCTGAACGTG   AAATTATTAGAATTACAAGGGATTGCC
 5. AACCAGAGCGTTCTGTTACGTGATGTGAACG   AAGTTGCGCCGGGTAGGCGTTACTTTGCTG
 6. AACGAAGTTCAGCCGCGTGCGAACGGTCAGG   GGTATACGCTTCTGCTTCACGAATGTATTGCTGTT
 7. AACTCGGGGCTCGGTCAGCACACCACGACCG   AAAGAGATCCTGACCAACGATATCTCTGAC
 8. AAGCGGTTGAGGAAGGGAAAATCGCGGAAAC   ACCGATCCGGGCTGCGCTATCCGGG
 9. AAGGCGCTCGTTGATGAACTGGAGCTGGCGC   AATTTCGCGTTGCAGTCTGACTCTGCACGTCTT
10. AATATCGACCAGCAATTCGCCTAAAAAGAAG   CCGCTGCCCGTGGATCAACCAGT
11. AATCCACACGTTCAGCAACCATCTCCAGCGT   ATCCACTGGACGAGCTACGCCGCTT
12. AATCGCGATATTTACACAGACCTAAATAGTC 
                                   
                               GCAAACACGATACCGATCCGGGCTGCGCTATCCGGGAAGCGGT


13. AATTTCCGGCGCGGCTTTATATTCCGGCAGA   ACAGACGCTCGCGAGT
14. ACCACCCAGCACGATGCCAGAAATCAGTGGG   AAACAGCGGCTCTCCACTGCCAGAGCAT
15. ACCAGCGTGCCTTCCATCATGTTCATTGCTA   GCAGATCCGTGCTAACGCGGTCGTT
16. ACTGTTCCGGCGTGGCATTAGGTGTTGATCG   CAGGCATACCGACTT
17. CCCTGGCCGTTTGCTTCGGCTTCGTGCTGGG   ACTCTGGGTGTTG


Suffix
 1. TAATGCCCTGATGCACGGCACC
 2. GTCTCGATATACAGACGCTCGCGAGTAATTT
 3. ATCCCCATCGCATTCA
 4. TGGATTATCCACTGGACGAGCTACG
 5. ATAACGCACAAACGCTGGCAAACCTGA
 6. TTGTACGCACGCGCCTCTTCGAGGATACGTTGCG
 7.  C
 8. CCGTTTCGAAAACTATC
 9. AGCTGTCTGCCAATAA
10. TCAATCGCGAGGCCGGTTCGTT
11. AGGGATTGCCAACACC
12. CTCAGGGCTTTGTCGAATTCCAT
13. AGTTTAGCAAAGCGCGCCACTTCACCCTGAGCTTCCAGG
14. CCATGCGTGCTGCCAATGTA
15. GCTGGATATTCTGGTTGATGATGGTCATGTTCGCGGCCTGG
16. CAACGCTAAAGGCGATGACTTCAGCCAGTGTCTCCGCGCCCAGCGCCAACATCACCAGA
17. TAGCTTCATGCTGTAATGATCAATCGCGGGGC
```

I have written the suffix column separately as it was not fitting in the same line.

Comment: Could you add more details? Also, can you clarify what you mean with the expression `suffix + macronode = prefix of next macronode + that next macronode`. Also can you define `maximum stretch`?

Comment: @zx8754 The expected output basically is the maximum number of this characters that are contiguously coming. As I mentioned the macronode's character + suffix's characters of that node is = prefix's characters of the next macronode + the characters of that next macronode.  For example if one macro node's characters are "ACGG" and the suffix attached to it "GGC" then this "ACGG" + "GGC"  which is "ACGGGGC" is equal to the next macronode's prefix which might be "ACG" + this next macronode's characters "GGGC"..

Comment: @yatu As I mentioned in the earlier comment that I gave to zx8754 I hope I could clear some doubts of the suffix + macronode = prefix of next macronode + that next macronode.   Maximum stretch can be defined as the maximum number of characters that can be reached contiguously.  This is basically checking the contiguity of a genome mapping that I have done. I can give more details if you need me to. Let me know.

Comment: An expected answer with a simple example would be helpful @Ashi

Comment: @zx8754 I have edited the original post and provided a toy example. Let me know if this helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also is that string the output that you expect? Wouldn't it be succession of `suffix + macronode` in the path? In this example `GCACACACT`?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question right: You are looking for a program that converts such a table to a graph (using pre- and suffixes to link up nodes) and then finds the longest path through all nodes without visiting a node twice?

Comment: @MartinWettstein yeah you can say it like that. I don't really need to construct any graph as the dataframe is itself an output of a graph I just need the longest contiguous path.

Comment: @Ashi: For this problem, it would be easier if you had the graph, though. Not the dataframe. It's a traveling salesman problem for which there are elegant approaches in graph theory but you need lots of brute force if you want to do it from a table like yours.

Comment: @Ashi BTW take a look at `dput` function for reusable data samples preparation.

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "_Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do [...] show your work!_". Currently your question may appear as a pure request for us to do _all_ your work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requirements were clarified a few times, I will post a new solution based on the graph theory (actually, the idea belongs to @Martin Wettstein, see comments to question). Of course, there could be problems in cases of cyclic graphs, still, that will be another question.

The script creates graph from the adjacency matrix and calculates the longest path (diameter) through the graph.

As provided subset of real data does not contain continuous sequences, I will use dummy data from the previous version of the answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
 
dat_txt <- "MacroNode        Prefix          Suffix
 GC                T               A
 CA                C               C
 AC                C               T
 CT                A               A
 GC                T               A
 CA                G               C
 AC                C               T
 CT                A               A"

# Concat strings
dat <- read.table(text = dat_txt, header = TRUE)
res <- dat %>%
  mutate(cur = paste0(MacroNode, Suffix),
         follow = paste0(Prefix, MacroNode),
         full = paste0(Prefix, MacroNode, Suffix))

# Prepare adjacency matrix
edge_mat <- outer(seq_len(nrow(res)), seq_len(nrow(res)), function(r, c) {
  return(res[r, "cur"] == res[c, "follow"])
})

# Construct graph
res_g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(edge_mat)

# Get the path with maximum length
g_diam <- get_diameter(res_g)

# Concatenate longest path
long_seq <- paste(res[g_diam, "full"], collapse = "")
```

Here is a result:

```
> long_seq
[1] "TGCAGCACCACTACTA"
```

Comment: Hi @Istrel thanks for the detailed code. I have run this code. I think this one is only comparing one row with its immediate next row but I need to check all the rows. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Ashi, I have added a procedure for a whole-table check. Please test it.

Comment: Thanks for rle() function. I used your code and the longest sequence is coming as " " (blank). I don't know if there is really no longest sequence present. I have also updated in the question giving all the 17 rows of the data frame that I am using.

Comment: I think I got where the code that you provided is having issues. See in my dataframe there is no guarantee that the contiguous macronodes are actually in the consecutive rows. It might be a case where the nodes that are actually contiguous are several rows apart. Shall I do any kind of sorting or binning to make them come in consecutive rows?

Comment: @Ashi I have changed the script, now it is a realisation of the graph theory approach, suggested by Martin Wettstein in comments.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if I understood but to combine all three cols into one you can use this:

```
df1$newcol ->  paste0(MacroNode, Prefix, Suffix)
```

If you want a space between each:

```
df1$newcol ->  paste0(MacroNode, " ",Prefix, " ",Suffix)
```

Comment: I doubt this is the expected output.